# How can I print out just the index of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make a table, and the way Pandas formats its indices is exactly what I'm looking for. That said, I don't want the actual data, and I can't figure out how to get Pandas to print out just the indices without the corresponding data.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can access the index attribute of a df using `.index`:

```
In [277]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(10), 'b':np.random.randn(10)})
df
Out[277]:
   a         b
0  0  0.293422
1  1 -1.631018
2  2  0.065344
3  3 -0.417926
4  4  1.925325
5  5  0.167545
6  6 -0.988941
7  7 -0.277446
8  8  1.426912
9  9 -0.114189
In [278]:

df.index
Out[278]:
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: For me it just prints `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)`, not the actual index column.

Comment: @RusI the index was refactored to be a `RangeIndex` type in later pandas versions. You can call `tolist()` on the object if you need the values, this only applies to `int` based indices

Answer (score 30):

`.index.tolist()` is another function which you can get the index as a list:

```
In [1391]: datasheet.head(20).index.tolist()
Out[1391]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Answer (score 11):

You can access the index attribute of a df using df.index[i]

```
>> import pandas as pd
>> import numpy as np
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(5), 'b':np.random.randn(5)})
   a         b
0  0  1.088998
1  1 -1.381735
2  2  0.035058
3  3 -2.273023
4  4  1.345342

>> df.index[1] ## Second index
>> df.index[-1] ## Last index

>> for i in xrange(len(df)):print df.index[i] ## Using loop
... 
0
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lamba function:

```
index = df.index[lambda x : for x in df.index() ]
print(index)
```

Comment: To use lambda:  ```print( (lambda x: x)(df.index) )```. However, ```print(df.index) ``` is sufficient as shown by  @EdChum. Lambda may be the way to go if one has to process the index in some way, like ```print( (lambda x: x*x)(df.index) )```.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try `df.index`. This function will show you the range index.

Or you can always set your index. Let say you had a weather.csv file with headers:
'date', 'temperature' and 'event'. And you want set "date" as your index.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csvte'weather_file)
df.set_index('day', inplace=True)
df
```